# Android UI Not Showing

Tags: android

My splash screen for my (very simple) Android application isn't showing. I have no idea why. Here's the code:

**QuizSplashActivity.java**

```
package com.ryanlin.triviaquiz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizSplashActivity extends QuizActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }
}
```

**splash.xml**

```
$<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/black"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/splash_textView_topTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/splash_topTitle"
    android:textColor="@color/splash_title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/splash_title"
/>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/splash_tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
>
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash1" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash3" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/splash4" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/splash_textView_bottomTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/splash_bottomTitle"
    android:textColor="@color/splash_title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/splash_title"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/splash_textView_version"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/splash_version"
    android:textColor="@color/splash_version"
    android:textSize="@dimen/splash_version"
    android:background="@color/splash_versionBG"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/splash_versionSpacing"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong? 
And don't tell me that the views aren't wrapped in a LinearLayout. They are, a LinearLayout is the root element, but I can't get the damn code formatting to work correctly for some strange reason. (It would also help if someone explains it to me)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any kind of exception in LogCat? Your ImageViews don't have layout_width or layout_height specified, which might be causing an exception when the layout is loaded.

Comment: Is the entire layout/UI not showing or only a portion of it?

Comment: @omizzle: Yes, the entire UI isn't showing.

Comment: @E.Z. Hart: I didn't see any exception in LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine AFAIK. How are you defining `@color/splash_title`? Most probably you're drawing everything black. Check it by using `android:background="#FFFFFFFF"` in your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, I figured out the problem. It wasn't in the layout files, it was in the base class (QuizActivity) some problem with SharedPreferences.